# Using JavaScript and DOM manipulation to create Cascading Drop Down but rendering incorrectly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a simple list that has two drop downs.  I am using JavaScript to create a cascading drop down functionality. A reference to my JavaScript file is placed in a content editor webpart of the list form and it functions perfectly. The problem is when I click submit, incorrect values are entered into the list.  Not sure why.  Please help!

Here's the set-up.  I have two lists.  A 'Service' list and a 'Service Category' lists.  A 1-many relationship.  When a value is select in the 'Service' list, that value is used to filter the 'Service Categories' list.

Here's an image for more clarity:
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert(document.querySelector("[title='Service']"));
cascadeDropDown();    
});


function cascadeDropDown(){
var service = document.querySelector("[title='Service']");

service.onchange = function(){
    var serviceSelection = service.options[service.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log("Service: "+serviceSelection);
    getServiceSubValue(serviceSelection);
}
}            

function getServiceSubValue(selectedValue){
//alert(selectedValue)

var category = document.querySelector("[title='Category']");
clearCategoryOption();
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Service%20Categories')/items?$filter=Service eq'" + selectedValue + "'";
var headers = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };        

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: endPointUrl,                            
                        type: 'GET',
                        headers: headers,
                        success: function(data){
                            //console.log(data.d.results);
                            //alert(data.d.results);
                            for(var i=1; i<data.d.results.length; i++){
                                console.log(data.d.results[i].Title);
                                console.log(i);
                                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                                opt.value = i;
                                opt.text = data.d.results[i].Title;
                                category.add(opt,null);
                            }
                        }
                   })
 }

 function clearCategoryOption(){
  var category = document.querySelector(" 
  [title='Category']").options.length=0;
 }
```

Comment: `Opt.value` should be the Id of item from Categories list.

Comment: Is this service and category columns are lookup used in third list?

Comment: My category column in my 'Service' list is a lookup into my 'Service Category'

Comment: And this form is of Service category list... Right?

Comment: The form is the 'Service' list

Comment: My "Service Category" list has the following columns, 'Service Category' and 'Service'.    My "Services" list has the following columns, 'Title', and 'Category' and 'Category' is a lookup into the "Service Category" list.

Comment: Try using `opt.value = data.d.results[i].ID` in your for loop and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: That worked but my Title is blank

Comment: Which title? There are only two columns in form service and category

Comment: How do I pick your solution as the answer?

Comment: Wait.. Adding answer. Please accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Category is lookup field from another list, you need to add the value of dropdown options to the Id's of the items of list from where you are looking up.

So you need use `opt.value = data.d.results[i].ID` in your for loop.

Comment: Argh!  It won't allow me to upvote b/c I have less than 15 reputations.

Comment: No problem. You got your answer that's important :)

Comment: haha..my reputation just went up. I upvoted the answer.  Thanks again!